# How can I install or update software with yum in CentOS 6 when CentOS 6 stopped its lifecycle?

Tags: centos, centos6, yum

I failed to install or update software in my CentOS 6 system these days. I guess CentOS removed their mirror list after CentOS 6 ends its lifecycle after Nov. 30.

I use this mirrorlist:

```
http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
```

Answer (score 5):

All things considered about security and it being EOL, you can still [make `yum` usable in CentOS 6](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/how-to-fix-yum-after-centos-6-went-eol):

```
curl https://www.getpagespeed.com/files/centos6-eol.repo --output /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
```

Or, update repo configuration manually.

Comment: This will get you access to the old software. But it will not give you updates as there aren't any more.

Comment: It won't. But depending on other repositories you use, updates may be there.

Comment: Solved my problem for tiny `128MB` VPS I just ordered , CentOS 6 didn't consume much RAM,having outdated software better than nothing .

Answer (score 2):

Officially there is nothing you can do with CentOS 6 - it's dead and buried - there will be no more updates from the CentOS project. From the CentOS-devel mailing list on 9th Nov 2020

> All,
>
> This is a friendly reminder.
>
> CentOS 6.10 will EOL at the end of November 2020.
>
> During the first week in December 2020, the 6.10 directory will move to
> vault.centos.org
>
> Packages will still be available at:
>
> http://vault.centos.org/centos/6.10/
>
> However, once moved, there will be no more updates pushed to
> vault.centos.org.  Therefore, security issues will no longer be fixed,
> etc.
>
> You should take the rest of the month to either move to a newer versoin
> of CentOS Linux ... or to procure Extended el6 support from Red Hat (EUS
> RHEL 6).

your best course of action is to upgrade to a supported OS version.

Answer (score 1):

From the CentOS forums:

> Red Hat have pulled the plug on RHEL 6.x as of Nov 30th 2020 and as a
> result CentOS 6 is now a dead version. The online yum repos for CentOS
> 6 have been archived to vault.centos.org and there will be no more
> updates to it at all, ever.

Answer (score -2):

https://vault.centos.org/

Is this what you are searching for?

Comment: Vault archiving old releases doesn't change the fact that CentOS 6 is dead. Upgrades should have been completed months ago.